# If you find the answer while writing your question, is the question still worth writing?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've just written out a question about using conditional logic inside the Console.WriteLine method of VB.NET, and in explaining the process found the answer (turns out that there's an If method that I wasn't aware of.) I couldn't find a similar question on the site. Is it ever in this scenario worth posting the question (and then later the answer, once the grace period expires,) to SO, or would most users just prefer I get on with what I'm doing?

Comment: Me personally, I would say no because in the *idea* behind SO, you should be doing research before posting your question. So logically speaking, if you were able to find the answer, others should as well. One thing I do to mitigate that ideal is I'll write in comments of answers I find: "For those trying to resolve *x* issue, **this** is the answer" or something along those lines with a little bit of context if need be.

Comment: I would say yes if you couldn't find the answer on this site.

Comment: I think well-written self-answered questions are a good thing and my impression is that they're generally encouraged as long as they're not duplicates. I think they're generally held to a higher standard in terms of quality, though, so make sure to take the time to write a really clear question

Comment: Welcome to how I solve 99% of my questions.

Comment: @Will I know what you mean. I've asked dozens of questions on Stack Overflow, but I've only hit the "Ask your question" button 4 times ever, because as I'm asking the question, providing sufficient details, boiling it down to a MCVE and everything, looking for duplicates, I tend to come up with my answer.

Comment: @Chris That's just simply **not** correct. The goal of SO is to `build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.`

Comment: @Clint I feel like you’re being pedantic. I feel like you understood what I meant by my post, but you went out of your way to try and correct me. I’m fully aware of what the essence of SO is; I was mainly speaking to the point of being able to find sufficient answers for questions. And since the OP is asking about a question he was originally going to ask, but yet found a solution to said problem through another, should it still be asked? Honestly, I would probably still ask anyway in the event that there is a better more efficient way; yet both of my answers elude to what was originally asked